# Codeigniter with facebook php sdk 3.2.3 logout is not working

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

Facebook logout is not working

i want when user click logout, user will logout from app as well as facebook.

<?php if ($this->session->userdata('user_id')) :

```
$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
$config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
$this->load->library('Facebook', $config);
$myurl = site_url('user/mainLogout'); 
$token= $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
$params = array('next' => $myurl,'access_token'=>$token);
$logoutUrl=$this->facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
```

?>

<li style="float:right"><a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl;//site_url('logout'); ?>">Logout </a></li>
<?php endif; ?>

In mainLogout()

function mainLogout(){

```
    $SessionArray = array(
        'user_id' => '',
        'user_email' => '',
        'role' => ''
    );
    $this->session->unset_userdata($SessionArray);
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->facebook->destroySession();
    setcookie('PHPSESSID', '', time()-3600, "/");
    setcookie ("fbss_XXXXXXXXXX", "", time() - 3600);
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
    redirect(site_url(''));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to destroy the session

using the following commands.

unset($_SESSION);
// Delete all session variables
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Hello Tabish, thanks for your reply, I tried it but it's not working.   in my facebook config file i set it as $config['appId']    = 'XXXXXXXXX';
 $config['secret']    = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
        $config['cookie']  = false;

Comment: I create a Logout.php file with the session unset code and called the facebook logOutUrl at the same time. like following  <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:1008/logout.php&quot;);">Logout</a>

Comment: Hello Tabish,

I solved this problem.

This problem happens due to facebook access_token, so i make it blank.

$this->facebook->setAccessToken('');

Last thanks for your reply.